# Groovy Nested Closures - how to pass a hash?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, closures

I'd like to load a closure for my Jenkins build, but pass it some variables that are generic to any type of build (Go, Java, Docker) that are going on on our system.   Since I'm loading the specific closure from a separate groovy file, it doesn't see those variables.    For the purposes of making a simpler example, I've commented out the load and included that closure.

I'm a little unsure about how to do this - how do I pass the config from buildProject to buildSpecificProject?    Am I referring to it wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/groovy

//def buildSpecificProject = load 'buildSpecificProject.groovy'

def buildSpecificProject = {  body->  

   def config = [:]
   body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
   body.delegate = config
   body()

   println config.name
   println config.builddirectory
}

def buildProject = { projbody -> 
   def config = [:]
   projbody.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
   projbody.delegate = config
   projbody()

   config.builddirectory = "/bar"

   return config
}

try {
    def newProjectVersion =  buildSpecificProject { body ->
      buildProject { projbody ->
         name = 'projectname'
         versionPrefix = "4.2.0"
         fetchFromURL = 'git@github.com:myorg/myproject.git'
      }
    }
    println "New Project Version = ${newProjectVersion}\n"
} catch (err) {
    println err
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with build scripts in Jenkins really, so maybe my answer is not applicable, but from a Groovy only perspective the situation is the following:

The config variable in buildSpecificProject is a local variable, to which itself you have no access, unless you expose it or its value. Right now you do that through the setting the delegate actually.

If we say buildProject is only called from within a block given to buildSpecificProject, then the block given to buildProject is a Closure nested into the Closure given to buildSpecificProject. This Closure object will have a property owner, which will refer to the enclosing Closure instance in this case (see http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_owner_of_a_closure). Of this we know it has set the configuration as delegate, thus you can do projbody.owner.delegate to access the configuration set by buildSpecificProject.

But actually I would consider doing something like this:

```
def buildSpecificProject = {  body ->  
  def config = [:]
  body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
  body.delegate = [config: config]  // expose config
  body()

  println config.name
  println config.builddirectory
  return config
}

def buildProject = { config, projbody -> 
   projbody()
   config.builddirectory = "/bar"
}

try {
    def newProjectVersion =  buildSpecificProject { body ->
      // make config accessible to buildProject by providing it as parameter
      buildProject(config) { projbody ->  
         config.name = 'projectname'
         config.versionPrefix = "4.2.0"
         config.fetchFromURL = 'git@github.com:myorg/myproject.git'
      }
    }
    println "New Project Version = ${newProjectVersion}\n"
} catch (err) {
    println err
}
```

As you can see it is actually enough for buildSpecificProject to set the delegate, which I set to a map with one key named config, containing the actual config. The disadvantage is of course, that you now have to do config.name. Also note the call "buildProject(config) { projbody ->", which gives the config to buildProject. And of course we can combine both ideas:

```
def buildSpecificProject = {  body ->  
  def config = [:]
  body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
  body.delegate = config
  body()

  println config.name
  println config.builddirectory
  return config
}

def buildProject = { config, projbody ->
   projbody()
   config.builddirectory = "/bar"
}

try {
    def newProjectVersion =  buildSpecificProject {
      buildProject(delegate) { projbody ->
         name = 'projectname'
         versionPrefix = "4.2.0"
         fetchFromURL = 'git@github.com:myorg/myproject.git'
      }
    }
    println "New Project Version = ${newProjectVersion}\n"
} catch (err) {
    println err
}
```

But I would recommend this not so much, as I do not like to depend on the delegate in this manner. I can break too easily.